# SailsJS returns a 200 Status Code Rather Than 304

Tags: rest, sails.js

I'm currently trying out the [Sails framework](http://sailsjs.org/) and so far I'm quite impressed. One of the odd things I noticed however is that the server returns a `200 OK` rather than a `304 Not Modified` status code for all records (even when unchanged).

Is there a way to make Sails return a 304 for unmodified records? The reason I'm asking is that this seems to be the [best practice](https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+best+practice+304+not+modified)  and used by some big players like [Google](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#HTTPStatusCodes) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/).

Comment: Are you checking the response codes using Google Chrome's web developer console?  It doesn't do caching, so you'll always get 200 for everything.  Use Firefox or Safari's dev tools if you want more accurate response codes.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I was using the "Postman" Chrome extension and was seeing only 200 OK.

Comment: Sorry for taking so much time to get back to you. I tried it in Firefox and Safari, both only gave 200 OK's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you simply have to set the `Last-Modified` header on your responses. 
["Sails is built on Express"](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Response/Response.html), which uses fresh (npmjs.org/package/fresh) to [compare the request and response headers](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/0120874b8e50c35355b0f21878e8909453abc15d/lib/request.js#L372).

Simple example (based on `Sails 0.10.0-rc5`):

1. `sails new test304response`
2. `cd test304response`
3. `sails generate api user` -> generates `User.js` and `UserController.js`
4. edit `api/models/User.js`

   ```js
   module.exports = {
       schema: true,
       attributes: {
           name: {
               type: 'string',
               required: true
           }
       }
   };
   ```
5. edit `api/controllers/UserController.js`

   ```js
   module.exports = {
       find: function (req, res, next) {
           console.log('find:', req.fresh);
           User.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundUser(err, user) {
               // set the Last-Modified header to the updatedAt time stamp 
               // from the model
               res.set('Last-Modified', user.updatedAt);
               res.json(user);
           });
       },
   };
   ```
6. `sails lift`
7. go to `localhost:1337/user/create?name=Joe` -> creates a new User
8. go to `localhost:1337/user/1` -> queries the User with id 1
9. refresh `localhost:1337/user/1` -> queries the same User, Last-Modified wasn't changed
10. The response has a `304 – Not Modified` status (even in the Chrome DevTools, which actually do caching as long as you don't explicitly disable it in the settings).

Disclaimer: I just started to learn sails and also node, so I might have missed a simpler/cleaner solution. I'm also not completely certain, that setting `Last-Modified` is enough in all cases. However, I had the feeling that you are more interested to know if it is possible and not to get a best practice implementation.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I wasn't allowed to include more than 2 links, please excuse the 'text links'.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Jan, got me thinking :). However, the problem is that I still don't have a way of knowing if the record was modified recently. The scenario I'm trying to solve is that I make a get to localhost:1337/user/1 and get an object; this should be a `200 OK`. Now, any subsequent requests to localhost:1337/user/1 should return a `304 - Not Modified` (unless of course the record has been changed elsewhere).

Comment: That should be exactly what happens here. The value of Last-Modified depends on updatedAt (wich is created by default). If user/1 is changed the timestamp from `updatedAt` will be different from the one in the request's `Last-Modified` header and you will get a `200`, if the user didn't change a `304` will be returned. Change the user, get a `200` again... If you could have another look and explain when/how exactly the example above is not solving your issue? I'm happy to improve the answer after that.

Comment: I guess the important thing is, that you of course have to implement a  check on the server that decides if a resource was modified or not. The example uses the `updatedAt` in your storage for that.

Comment: Wow, I just re-read my comment and realize I was way too deep into the ORM/Waterline stuff. You're absolutely correct, providing a last modified header will resolve this. Thanks Jan, and thank you for not taking me out at the knees over my obviously incorrect comment!